# Mongoose setting default array size and values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to setup a default array size and value in my mongoose schema, but the return is always appearing as `[]` unless the document actually has data.

```
"transform": { type: [ Number ], default: [0, 0, 0] }
```

Return value is:

```
"transform":[]
```

How do I configure my schema so it returns:

```
"transform":[0,0,0]
```

**Answer**:
Setting `required: true` will add the data to any new documents created. Old documents will not be updated, however.

```
"transform": { type: [ Number ], default: [0, 0, 0], required: true }
```

**Update**
To quickly resolve my data issue I ran an update on Mongo to upgrade all existing documents using the following line.

```
db.getCollection('objects').updateMany(
    { "properties.transform": []}, 
    { $set: { "properties.transform" : [0,0,0] }}
);
```

NOTE: My transform field is a child of properties hence the `"properties.transform"`

Comment: zero is seen as empty

Comment: Is there anyway to override that? I suppose I could use 1,1,1 (just tested and it works), but it's not ideal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my schema to add default values in mongoose arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845282/why-doesnt-my-schema-to-add-default-values-in-mongoose-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its either you set required to true in the schema. Or false, which defaults to empty. You can't have both ways in this case either empty or provide a value.

A hack you could use is this. 
Just set required to true, and upon data entry initially push array of zeroes.

```
model.push([0,0,0]);
```

Comment: Got it, I was testing on previously generated documents, I just ran an update with default set to 0 and required true, and the new documents have returned [0,0,0]

Comment: nice bro! previously generated documents caused it