# How do you create a schema that can change depending on the user's input?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Just for funsies, I'm creating a similar app to UberEAT.

The database would probably hit the collection limit, so I created two separate collections.

First, I need the restaurant info, so I structured it like this:

```
var PlaceSchema = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  menuID: Number,
  name: String,
  cuisine_type: String, (eg; thai, korean, sushi ,etc)
  address: String,
  opening_time:Date,
  closing_time:Date
});
```

Then I need to show the menu the restaurant have, the problem is each restaurant have a different number of dishes and prices, so the quantity is not constant.

This is how I structured my menu data, but I know it's completely wrong

```
var MenuSchema = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  parentID: Number,
  name: String,
  price: Number

});
```

any guidance would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this to get started

for restuarant

```
var PlaceSchema = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  menusId: [Number],
  name: String,
  cuisine_type: String, (eg; thai, korean, sushi ,etc)
  address: String,
  opening_time:Date,
  closing_time:Date
});
```

and for menus

```
var MenuSchema = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  placeId: Number,
  dishes: [{name: String, price: Number}] //add any other dish related stuff here, like spiceness, app, entree, desert chef special etc etc
});
```

Now you can have multiple menus for a place, and multiple dishes in a menu. 
You can even do array of places Id in the menu, which could be a case if bunch of restaurants same menu.

```
var MenuSchema = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  placesId: [Number],
  dishes: [{name: String, price: Number}] //add any other dish related stuff here, like spiceness, chef special etc etc
});
```

**Updated for drinks with default**
here is an updated menu schema with drinks
    var MenuSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    placeId: Number,
    dishes: [{name: String, price: Number}], //add any other dish related stuff here, like spiceness, app, entree, desert chef special etc etc

```
 drinks:[{
    name: String,
    price: Number
    }]
 });
```

Like I said in the comment, mongoose doesn't really have any default for arrays.
But we can write a pre save hook to take care of this.

```
MenuSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    if (!this.drinks.length) {
        this.drinks.push({name: "No Drinks", price: 0}); //null or 0 whichever you pefer
    }
    next();
});
```

This will default in a default object as described above.

P.S. This defaulting drinks as "No Drinks" doesn't feel right though. Maybe keep it as an empty array, and when we need to use it in the code, to display or whatever just check for the length.

```
  if (!menu.drinks.length) {
     console.log("No drinks");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would you insert the dishes in your menu schema? I tried 
    `dishes:[
      "Panini", 3.50,
      "Waffle", 2.50]`  but it didnt work.

Comment: You would dishes [{name: Panini, cost: 3.5}, {name: waffle, cost:2.5}]

Comment: It works :)! One last thing, if you were to add a default value in the schema, how would you do so? I tried it with `drinks: {type: [{name: String, price: Number}], default: "No drinks" },` and it didn't work.

Comment: according to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845282/why-doesn't-my-schema-to-add-default-values-in-mongoose-arrays default values don't really work with arrays. So following his advice, we can write a pre save function that does what we need. I am going to put the code in updated section of the answer.