# Mongoose | MongoDB | Default values not populating

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to stick pre-populated data into my mongoDB database but the default data isn't getting in there when I send a POST request with the email and password only. Instead, all I'm seeing is an empty array titled 'thisiswhereIwantthetestdata'.

I tried adding default data at the top-level and that worked when I sent a POST request with the email and password only.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Maybe something to do with the way I refer to [testSchema]?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  test: {
    type: String,
    default: 'default test'
  },
  test2: {
      type: String,
      default: 'default test 2'
  }
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  thisiswhereIwantthetestdata: [testSchema]
});
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31847002/11717458

Comment: @SuleymanSah it does, but now I'm super confused because I added in: `userSchema.pre('save',function(next) {
  if (this.thisiswhereIwantthetestdata.length == 0)
    this.thisiswhereIwantthetestdata.push('testingmongodb');

  next();
});` and instead of seeing 'testingmongodb' anywhere I see the correct values in 'test' and 'test2'. I tried sending an empty .push() and that created an error, any idea why this random magic is working or where the string 'testingmongodb' goes?

Comment: Check my answer please. I changed thisiswhereIwantthetestdata field name to more meaningfull tests field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a pre save hook like this:

User schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  test: {
    type: String,
    default: "default test"
  },
  test2: {
    type: String,
    default: "default test 2"
  }
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    // unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tests: [
    {
      type: testSchema,
      default: testSchema
    }
  ]
});

userSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  if (this.tests.length == 0) this.tests.push({});

  next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Sample route to create user:

```js
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await User.create(req.body);

  res.send(result);
});
```

When you send a post request to the route with this body:

```
{
    "email": "a@b.net",
    "password": "123123"
}
```

Response will be like this meaning default values worked:

```
{
    "_id": "5de6b94ad440d0337c8fd388",
    "email": "a@b.net",
    "password": "123123",
    "tests": [
        {
            "test": "default test",
            "test2": "default test 2",
            "_id": "5de6b94ad440d0337c8fd389"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```