# How to add a data in an array in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to get defaultAccountId and display to the user and if the user login with same email and password but different defaultAccountId I need to add that defaultAccountId to buisnessUnit.I need to display the buisnessUnit with all the deafaultId that entered by the user in array.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const db = require('_helpers/db');
const Post = db.Post;



const sschema = new Schema({
    defaultAccountId:{
        type:Number,
   required:true

    }
});


const schema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true
    },

    hash: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    defaultAccountId:{
        type:Number,
        required:true

    },
   
    buisnessUnit:{
        type:Array,
       

        
    },
    
    createdDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    lastLoginDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
schema.statics.login = function login(id, callback) {
    return this.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { '$set' : { 'lastLoginDate' : Date.now() },  new : true }, callback);
 };



schema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding a default single value, you can do something like below.

```
buisnessUnit:{
    type:Array,
    default:
}
```

For an array please read the question on stackoverflow.
[Why doesn't my schema to add default values in mongoose arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845282/why-doesnt-my-schema-to-add-default-values-in-mongoose-arrays)

Comment: I just named it as an defaultAccount ID but it is not default one....please help me out.....I am a total beginner...........